# HL7 messaging using Mule ESB Community

Tags: mule, messaging, soa, mule-studio, hl7

Mule Healthcare Toolkit is a collection of features that facilitates integration with healthcare systems by providing the tools needed to easily create, read and transform HL7 version v2.x messages within Mule... Unfortunately, it is available only for Mule ESB Enterprise!!!
Is there a way to implement a complete messaging service based on HL7 using the Community version of Mule?

Best regards, Vi.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel has HL7 components that you can use to create HL7 routes. You could possibly then route this to mule via a web service call or a JMS call being hosted by the Mule ESB for example.

Apache camel does not require a full ESB (it is not a ESB) so it could act as some sort of translator proxy.

Might not be your cup of tea though.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but it appears that the Mule Healthcare Toolkit uses the open source HAPI library for (at least some of) the HL7 v2 message support. You'd have examine it more closely, but I suspect one could create their own Mule components using HAPI.

http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/